# No Devices on shell

Tags: adb, shell, root-access

I try to send an intent using an android-shell. The app starts, "su" works nice, but when I enter something like `"adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"` I receive an error:

```
error: device not found
```

when trying to list the devices with

```
adb devices
```

the result list is empty.

WHat am I am doing wrong? (My tablet is rooted, of course)

Comment: Do you have USB debugging enabled?

Comment: Yes. But should not matter as I am not connecting by USB but have a console-App directly on my device

Comment: AFAIR the adb deamon on the device is only running if USB debugging is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the terminal app on your device then you don't need to use "adb shell". You just need to run the "am broadcast -a android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON". I don't know why you would want to run that from your terminal app since the screen would already be on.

You need to have USB debugging on if you are trying to connect via the console on your PC to your device. You also need to have the drivers installed if you are using a Windows machine.

Comment: SCREEN_ON was just the maximum simple example to show my problem. Atually I use "org.prowl.torque.REQUEST_TORQUE_QUIT" to end the torque-App